# isLoading doesnt strap fetching

Tags: reactjs, node.js, react-hooks

I am connecting my Node.js api to my React app. Here, I have this isLoading state variable, which is ment to render a spinner while fetching happens, but console.log(planes) after if statement still logs [] before actual data from backend. How do I fix this?

`if(planes.length == 0)` worked in the beggining, but with the plane variable it doesnt fit

Help would be really aprriciated!

```
function App() {

  const [ planes, setPlanes ] = useState([]);
  const [ plane, setPlane ] = useState();
  const [ id, setId ] = useState(0);
  const [ isLoading, setIsLoading ] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const fetchedPlanes = await getAllPlanes();
        if (Array.isArray(fetchedPlanes)) {
          setPlanes(fetchedPlanes);
        } else {
          console.error("Error: getAllPlanes did not return an array");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching planes:", error);
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };
  
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  function handleId(id) {
    setId(id);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if(id == 0) {
      return
    }
    setIsLoading(true);
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const fetchedPlane = await getPlaneById(id);
        if (fetchedPlane) {
          setPlane(fetchedPlane);
        } else {
        console.error("Error fetching a plane")
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [id]);

  if(isLoading) {
    return <Spin />;
  } 
  console.log(planes);
  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value = {{plane, planes, handleId}}>
      ...
    </DataContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: 1) please add your backend function, ( getAllPlanes can return promise or string instead of array) 2) please check your question two more times, Inglish is not our first language and expressing an issue is hard, but reading is hardier.

Answer (score 0):

Your empty-dependency effect hook runs on component mount.

This means that `setIsLoading(true)` runs **after** the component is mounted. The `isLoading` state change will take effect on the next render.

If you want to make sure that the `isLoading` state is *truthy* when the component is mounted, initialise it as such

```js
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
```